# Why do Unix IPC solutions lose throughput performance beyond 16 MiB in custom benchmark?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, ipc

I would like to evaluate the raw performance of some common IPC solutions on Unix systems. As a starting point, I have created several small benchmark programs, designed to send binary data from a forked client to a server (1 KiB – 512 MiB in size, each iteration doubling the previous size). By locking the timestamps on both processes, it should be possible to estimate the throughout by dividing the data size with the elapsed time.

Everything seems to work, however I don't understand why all of the results fall sharply beyond 16 MiB and then stagnate, as visible in the following diagram:

[image: Unix IPC throughput]

For reference, the abbreviations are designated as follows: uds (Unix domain socket), fifo (FIFO), fifoenh (Enhanced FIFO = increased local and global FIFO size), mmap (POSIX shared memory), tcp (TCP socket), mq (POSIX message queue), zmq-ipc-pr (ZeroMQ).

I have attached the sample program used to evaluate the throughput of Unix domain sockets (error checking omitted for clarity). All others work similar:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

typedef struct {
    sem_t sem;
} MySem;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // setup log file
    std::stringstream fileName;
    fileName << "uds" << "_";
    std::ofstream logFile;

    // setup semaphore & place in shared memory
    size_t szMySem = sizeof(MySem);
    MySem* pSem = (MySem*)mmap(NULL, szMySem, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&pSem->sem, 1, 0);

    // remove, if present
    unlink("/tmp/uds.uds");

    struct sockaddr_un udsAddr;
    memset(&udsAddr, 0, sizeof(udsAddr));
    udsAddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(udsAddr.sun_path, "/tmp/uds.uds");

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0)
    {
        // parent (server = reader)
        fileName << "server.csv";
        logFile.open(fileName.str());

        int sockFd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        bind(sockFd, (struct sockaddr*)&udsAddr, sizeof(udsAddr));
        listen(sockFd, 10);

        // inform client that socket is ready
        sem_post(&pSem->sem);

        socklen_t addrlen = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
        int connFd = accept(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *) &udsAddr, &addrlen);

        // from 1 KiB to 512 MiB
        for(int szKiB = 1; szKiB < 1048576; szKiB = szKiB * 2)
        {
            int szBytes = szKiB * 1024;

            // 100 runs for each size to attain average
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                // create buffer
                std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> pBuf(new uint8_t[szBytes]);

                uint32_t allBytesRead = 0;
                while(allBytesRead != szBytes)
                {
                    // read() blocks until data is available
                    uint32_t bytesRead = read(connFd, (void*)(pBuf.get() + allBytesRead), szBytes);
                    allBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }

                // lock current time after read
                long timeStamp = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());
                logFile << szBytes << ";" << i << ";" << 2 << ";" << allBytesRead << ";;" << timeStamp << std::endl;

                // inform client that it can send next data package
                sem_post(&pSem->sem);
            }
        }

        // cleanup
        close(connFd);
        close(sockFd);
        unlink("/tmp/uds.uds");
        // remove semaphore from shared memory
        munmap(pSem, szMySem);
        logFile.close();
    }

    else
    {
        // child (client = writer)
        fileName << "client.csv";
        logFile.open(fileName.str());

        // wait until server has set up socket
        sem_wait(&pSem->sem);

        int sockFd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        connect(sockFd, (struct sockaddr*)&udsAddr, sizeof(udsAddr));

        // from 1 KiB to 512 MiB
        for(int szKiB = 1; szKiB < 1048576; szKiB = szKiB * 2)
        {
            int szBytes = 1024 * szKiB;

            // 100 runs for each size to attain average
            for(int it = 0; it < 100; it++)
            {
                // create buffer
                std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> pBuf(new uint8_t[szBytes]);
                // char 'A'
                memset(pBuf.get(), 0x41, szBytes);

                // lock current time before write
                long timeStamp = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
                            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());

                uint32_t allBytesWritten = 0;
                while(allBytesWritten != szBytes)
                {
                    uint32_t bytesWritten = write(sockFd, (void*)(pBuf.get() + allBytesWritten), szBytes);
                    allBytesWritten += bytesWritten;
                }

                logFile << szBytes << ";" << it << ";" << 1 << ";;" << allBytesWritten << ";" << timeStamp << std::endl;

                // wait until server has read data
                sem_wait(&pSem->sem);
                // then wait 1 sec before next send
                sleep(1);
            }
        }

        // cleanup
        close(sockFd);
        logFile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All tests were performed on an AWS EC2 md5.large instance (Intel Xeon Platinum 8175 @ 3.1 GHz, 8 GB RAM, Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS x64). Any hints as to what might cause this peculiar behavior are welcome.

Comment: The stagnation is likely down to filling up the caches, after which performance is limited by the speed of the SDRAM - much slower.